# How do i declare a non inclusive floating point range in ada?

Tags: range, ada

Declaring ranges in Ada is always done inclusively.
If i want a type that has all the integers from `0` to `42` (or as a mathmatical interval: `[0, 42]`) i declare it as follows:

```
type zero_to_42 is range 0 .. 42;
```

If i want to exclude the zero (the range `(0, 42]`), this is not an issue for discrete types:

```
type not_zero_to_42 is range (zero_to_42'First + 1) .. zero_to_42'Last;
```

but i still have to do this manually, there is no `zero_to_answer'NextAfterFirst`

For floating point types i have no idea how to do this properly. It's simple for excluding the zero, but excluding anything else seems implementation defined to me.

```
type works is digits 6 range 0.0 .. 42.0
type also_works is new works range (0.0 + works'small) .. 42.0
type broken is new works range 0.0 .. (42.0 - works'small)
```

since float values near `42.0` have less precision than floating point values near `0.0`, `42.0 - works'small` is rounded to `42.0`
i could of course find a value by hand that works (e.g. `41.9999`) but that seems ugly to me and might not work anymore when i change the number of digits that `works` has.

Comment: I don't think the language defines `'small` for floating-point types; the attribute is intended for fixed-point.  Implementors are allowed to define their own attributes, although I'm not sure if they're allowed to define a language-defined attribute in a place where the language doesn't define it.  In any case, using `'small` on a floating-point type appears to give an implementation-defined result and is not portable.

Comment: @ajb correct about 'Small but there is 'Fraction attribute for floating point types. Also implementations are permitted to add new (non-standard) attributes but they have to be documented in user guide. One can use pragma (don't remember which one) to prohibit implementation defined attributes.

Comment: @darkestkhan (1) `'Fraction` on a positive number always returns a result between 0.5 and 1, so it is not suitable here.  (2) RM 4.1.4(12) says that new attributes usually can't have the same identifier as language-defined ones, so an implementation shouldn't define its own `'small` unless it was defined in Ada 83.  (3) `pragma Restrictions(No_Implementation_Attributes)` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'Succ` and `'Pred` attributes can be used on floating-point values to return the next or previous machine numbers.  If `T` is a floating-point type,

```
T'Succ(X)
```

is the smallest floating-point "machine number" `> X`, and

```
T'Pred(X)
```

is the largest floating-point machine number `< X`.  Thus:

```
type Works is digits 6 range 0.0 .. 42.0;
subtype Exclusive is Works range 0.0 .. Works'Pred(42.0);
```

Or (since the range on the `type` declaration might not be relevant):

```
type Digits_6 is digits 6;
subtype Exclusive is Digits_6 range 0.0 .. Digits_6'Pred(42.0);
```

Or

```
type Exclusive is digits 6 range 0.0 .. Float'Pred(42.0);
```

assuming you know `Float` is a 32-bit IEEE float and `Exclusive` will also be one.

Answer (score 2):

What is can be used here is `'Adjacent(near_value, towards_value)`

```
type works is digits 6 range 0.0 .. 42.0
type also_works is new works range (0.0 + works'small) .. 42.0
type still_works is new works range 0.0 .. works'Adjacent(42.0, 0.0)
```

this looks for whichever value can be represented by the machine that is closest to `near_value` in the direction of `towards_value`

when printing out `still_works'last` and `works'last` very likely the result will look/be the same, but comparing the two won't work

```
declare
  type works is digits 6 range 0.0 .. 42.0
  subtype still_works is works range 0.0 .. works'Adjacent(42.0, 0.0)
begin
  Text_IO.Put_Line(works'Image(works'Last));
  Text_IO.Put_Line(still_works'Image(still_works'Last));
  Text_IO.Put_Line(Boolean'Image(works'Last = still_works'Last));
end;
```

yields when compiled with gnat:

```
4.20000E+01
4.20000E+01
FALSE
```

Comment: I think `works'Pred(42.0)` should be equivalent, although `'Adjacent` perhaps makes the intent clearer.

Comment: `'Pred` and `'Succ` were what i was looking for! Thanks! if you add an answer i will select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the Ada 2012 dynamic predicate:

```
   type Exclusive is new Float range 0.0 .. 42.0
     with Dynamic_Predicate => Exclusive > 0.0 and then Exclusive < 42.0;
```

but GNAT seems to have troubles with this: GCC 4.8.1 is OK, GNAT GPL 2013 won’t even accept values of 1.0 or 41.0, and GCC 4.9.0-20140119 threw a bug box!